# How do you return a boolean by comparing three variables on the same line?

Tags: java, if-statement, return, conditional-statements, code-cleanup

I've seen people doing an if and else statement on only 1 line using

`return var1 != null ? var2 : 0;`.

This seems quite more compact and quicker to type than making an if statement and then a few more lines and so on...

The return statement above is an example, I could not recreate something similar as I don't know the syntax of using `if and else` statements on `return` lines.

---

The current situation:

There are 3 integers.

I want to compare **if var 1 is bigger than var 2** and also (**&&**) **if (var 1 + var 3) is bigger than var 2**.
If those conditions are true then the return statement should return false else true.

Attempt:

```
return var1 > var2 && (var1 + var3) > var2 ? false : true;
```

Comment: Aside: you should never write `condition ? false : true`: `!condition` is simpler.

Comment: @Eran yes exactly, thanks for the correction, updated thread as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"If `var1` is bigger than `var2`" is this condition:

```
var1 > var2
```

"If `var1 + var3` is bigger than `var2`" is this condition:

```
var1 + var3 > var2
```

Return false if both those conditions match, otherwise true:

```
return !(var1 > var2 && var1 + var3 > var2);
```

Alternatively, you can negate the individual conditions, which gives:

```
return (var1 <= var2 || var1 + var3 <= var2);
```

(which is equivalent as long as none of your numbers is NaN.)

There is no need for the `?:` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't

```
return !(var1 > var2 && (var1 + var3) > var2);
```

is enough?

Using boolean algebra, we can simplify the `!` operator: `!(a and b) = !a or !b`

```
return var1 <= var2 || (var 1 + var 3) <= var2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can type:

```
return !(var1 > var2 && (var1 + var3) > var2);
```

Comment: @Mike That's always the developer's choice. If the OP wants a one-liner, maybe that matters more than readability... and that becomes a question of styles or opinions.